# Height row mismatch because the presence of an img tag

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a problem with styling a table with CSS. I'm using a div to wrap up a table element. The problem arises when I insert an img tag into one cell. It's height changes. I have tried to set the height of the row elements with no luck.   Here's the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/PUqm8/embedded/result/). My objective is to 
add an image to fit all the cell space without changing it's size. I'll appreciate all the help.

Note: all the rows must have the same height and the size must be in percentage.

**html**

```
<div id="client">
<table>
    <col id="col1" />
    <col id="col2" />
    <col id="col3" />
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img id="profilePhoto" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTjelu9edzZ0fit_oqWGlHKS8koq1Vc56_u0XiYJynYbQmKSuQTCA" />
        </td>
        <td>2a</td>
        <td>3a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">2b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="row">2c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1d</td>
        <td colspan="2">2d</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**css**

```
html {
height: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
body {
height: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
body #client {
outline:solid 1px;
width: 75%;
height: 25%;
overflow: hidden;
}
table {
width: 70%;
height:100%;
table-layout:fixed;
}
td {
text-align: center;
border: solid thin;
overflow: hidden;
}
#profilePhoto {
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're asking for. Do you mean you want the image to keep its natural size, or the cell to keep its natural size, or something else entirely?

Comment: the cell must keep its size regardless of the image @metadept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to give up the easy centering of your image, this should work:

```
td {
    position: relative;
}

#profilePhoto {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PUqm8/1/

Comment: it would be nicer if the image could take all the cell space, but your solution it's the best i have seen. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding attribute `rowspan="3"`, put the image in a div, and make the overflow hidden for it. Also, since theres no more rowspan, dont forget to add a new cell in the 2nd and 3rd rows

```
<td>
    <div style="height:30px;overflow:hidden;">
        <img id="profilePhoto" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTjelu9edzZ0fit_oqWGlHKS8koq1Vc56_u0XiYJynYbQmKSuQTCA"/>
    </div>
</td>
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/fdAqn/

Comment: The table must have the rowspan attribute and the height must be in percentage

Answer (score 0):

Try setting  td height:

```
td{
    text-align: center;
    border: solid thin;
    overflow: hidden;
    height:10px;
}
```

Comment: the height must be in percentage @slaker